# Live Server icon on status bar in VSC

Tags: visual-studio-code

This is my first question in this forum. I have annoying problem:
I cannot  add Live Server icon on my status bar and thus I am not able to preview my page.
I have used LS before but it's been attaching it's icon automatically.
I've already checked option i confid which was suppose to do that but it is enabled.
Any idea? please help

Answer (score 0):

First you must install Live Server in the packet of VS Code

Then you can click right mouse on your HTML Code and choose Open with Live Server

Comment: I had tried this before I wrote this post. Unfortunatelly it only shows me a mesaage "Open a folder or a workspace..(File-->Open File)"

Comment: I figured it out by pressing mouse right button on my index.html file in file browser window and Open with Live server as you have mentioned. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try right-clicking on the status bar (i.e., the bar located at the bottom) to bring up the following menu. See if there's a tick next to "Live Server (Extension)". If not, click on this item and you should be able to see the Live Server button in the status bar.

[image: live extension option]